# Schedule the SSIS package to run on a schedule

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am building my first SSIS package which imports a flat file from a folder on File share into a SQL Sever DB table. I have another settings table on the SQL server DB where the Start time is stored, I need to query this table and run my package at that time. If the Settings table has 13:00 as start time, I need to run the SSIS package at 13:00 and check if the file exists in the file share, if the file exists it is imported in to DB else I need to send out an email notification to email alias.

I have built the package that can import the data from the FF to SQL server DB and it is working as expected. But wanted know if the scheduling piece is doable and how we can achieve that. Any suggestion/help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should add the file exists and email steps to the SSIS package that way the one single package can take care of that.

As for the scheduling, you can do that yes.
Create an Agent job that runs say hourly with 2 steps
step 1 can call a stored proc or run your tsql code that does the checks you need, if you exit it with a success code it will then run step 2 which would be your SSIS package.